# Token undefined

Tags: express, jwt, token, express-jwt

I am facing an undefined token issue. I have a local frontend where I verify the login, and when clicking the access button, the client has a token generated and guarantees a GET method that sends this token in the header of my /tasks route.

```
try {
          const response = await fetch("/authentication/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, senha }),
          });

          if (response.ok) {
            const responseData = await response.json();
            const token = responseData.token;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token)

            const responseTask =  await fetch("/tasks", {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "Authorization":"Bearer " + token,
              }
            })
            
            if (responseTask.ok){
              console.log("ok:" + token)
              window.location.href = "/tasks"
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Erro ao fazer a solicitação:", error);
          alert(
            "Erro ao fazer a solicitação. Verifique o console para mais detalhes."
          );
        }
      });
    </script>
```

The middleware checks the token and normally it should redirect to my tasks page without problems, when I don't redirect, in the console I can see all the cute tokens, see the middleware code:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const express = require("express");

const verificarAutenticacao = async (req, res, next) => {
  const autToken = req.headers.authorization;
  const secret = process.env.SECRET;

  if (!autToken) {
    res.status(401).json({ menssagem: "Não autorizado" });
  }

  console.log("Token de Autorização:", autToken);
  
  
  //desestruturando os dados do autToken pois ele vem com um Barear e o que me interessa é apenas o token
  const token = autToken.split(" ")[1];
  console.log("O token é: ", token)



  try {
    jwt.verify(token, secret);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ menssagem: "Token Inválido" });
  }
};


module.exports = verificarAutenticacao;
```

The problem arises when I redirect a user to the protected page in the /tasks route, my token simply disappears, my middleware no longer receives the token and it returns an error.

When debugging my autToken, which is the variable that receives the complete token and then separates the barear from the token, it doesn't even receive a value. Returning this to me:

```
Token de Autorização: undefined
C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\middleware\verificarAutenticacao.js:16
  const token = autToken.split(" ")[1];
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at verificarAutenticacao (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\middleware\verificarAutenticacao.js:16:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:110:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\todo-list\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Node.js v21.1.0
```

I tried to do a separate get in the frontend of my task, I already tried to observe the headers that were coming and they come with a token:

`cabeçalho da tasks:  {"host":"localhost:5050","connection":"keep-alive","sec-ch-ua":"\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\"","sec-ch-ua-mobile":"?1","authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...`